# No match for operator== in generic function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-function

I have the code below, I'm attempting to write a generic function which takes 2 iterators and an object and checks for any occurrences and returns the number of occurrences.

below my simple class

```
class person{

 string name;
 int age;

 public:
 person(string n, int a): name(n), age(a) {}
 bool operator==(person &p);

};

bool person::operator==(person &p){

 return (name == p.name && age == p.age);

}
```

Below is the generic function

```
template<typename Iter, typename Obj>
int count_obj(Iter iter1, Iter iter2, Obj &obj){
 int count = 0;
 for (; iter1 != iter2; iter1++){
  if((*iter1) == obj)
  count += 1;

 }

 return count;
}
```

my main:

```
int main(){
vector<person *> myp;

person a("ted", 21); person b("sun", 100); person c("ted", 21);
myp.push_back(&a);myp.push_back(&b);myp.push_back(&c);

cout<< "occurences for person objects " << count_obj(myp.begin(), myp.end(), a) << '\n'; 

}
```

Full error

```
3b.cc: In function ‘int count_obj(Iter, Iter, Obj&) [with Iter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<person**, std::vector<person*> >, Obj = person]’:
3b.cc:61:79:   instantiated from here
3b.cc:42:3: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘iter1.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = person**, _Container = std::vector<person*>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = person*&]() == obj’
make: *** [3b] Error 1
```

I cant seem to figure out I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a vector of `person *`, and you're trying to compare them against a `person`.  You will need to modify the line of code in `count_obj` to be either:

```
if (*(*iter1) == obj)
```

or:

```
if ((*iter1) == &obj)
```

depending on whether you wish to compare pointers or objects.

[*Note: Are you aware of the [`std::count`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/) function in the standard library?*]

[*Note (2): As mentioned in another answer, you should probably read up on "const correctness".  You should declare your `operator==` as `const`, and it should take a `const` reference as an argument.*]

[*Note (3): Storing raw pointers in a container is often a bad idea.  For instance, are you aware that you effectively have a memory leak?*]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this indeed was the problem. But the count returned by my function is always 1, when it should be 2. What could be the issue?

Comment: @cody: If you use the first variant I posted, it should do what you were hoping for.

Comment: ok thanks. I wanted to use vector<person *> myp; and then push_back references for objects to prevent copies, if that makes sense. So my question is what would be recommended push_back(&a) or just push_back(a). Is it any more efficient by reference?